# How to change VM resolution to higher Hyper-V?

Tags: display, resolution, hyper-v, hyper-v-manager

I am trying to increase the resolution of the VM window.
However I am not able to find the setting anywhere within Hyper-V manager.

Even in full screen mode I see VM doesnt occupy entire screen. I do remember it asked for resolution during first time set up, but I dont know how to change it now , I want it to be full screen or my custom length x width.

This is how it looks now in Full screen mode , occupying black background
[image]

I have tried changing below options with no luck

> Hyper-V settings -> Enhanced Session Mode

and

> Hyper-V settings -> Reset Check boxes

Also added below text in config files located at **C:\Users\Prateek\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V\Client\1.0**

- clientsettings.config
- user.config
- virtmgmt.VMBrowser.config
- vmconnect.config
- vmwizards.config

```xml
<setting name="FullScreen" type="System.Boolean">
    <value>False</value>
</setting>
<setting name="DesktopSize" type="System.Drawing.Size">
    <value>1920, 1080</value>
</setting>
```

### Guest OS(Ubuntu 18.4.3 Display settings

[image]

Comment: You change the resolution in the VM's OS, not Hyper-V Manager.  If you have a Hyper-V aware OS that can use enhanced session that's where you'd get the question about the screen resolution.

Comment: @essjae [Ubuntu 18.04 seems to be Hyper-V aware](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/supported-ubuntu-virtual-machines-on-hyper-v) but Settings display shows *Unknown Display* at 1152x864(4:3)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way to change your resolution is via the following:

1. Open **Terminal**
2. Enter `sudo vi /etc/default/grub`
3. Find the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`
4. Modify the line with the resolution you want, ex: 1920x1080: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=hyperv_fb:1920x1080"`
5. Write the changes to vi and quit, `ESC wq`
6. Enter `sudo update-grub`
7. Reboot the VM

--if you can use the "Quick Create" option in Windows 10 Hyper-V, I believe you'll get a better experience and the ability to adjust the resolution on the fly.  It doesn't seem that you can configure a manual install to do this.

Comment: `sudo update-grub` --> `command not found`

Comment: My CentOS 6 VM doesn't contain the file `/etc/default/grub`. Also, is there a way to set the resolution dynamically, not to some default "1920x1080" value?