# Hyper-V Enhanced Session on Windows 10 "19H2" 1909 not working

Tags: hyper-v

I have searched all over to try and solve this and so far I came out empty handed. Basically, I have Windows 10 PRO and installed Hyper-V since VirtualBox just doesn't want to work even with all the necessary modules installed.

So my problem is that after installing Hyper-V I tried to install a VM quickly (Ubuntu 18.04) and my resolution was locked to 1152x800 or something like that. I did turn on all the prerequisites :

1) Enhanced Session Mode Policy 2) Enhanced Session Mode

and I still have Enhanced Session greyed out. This also happens with a Windows 10 Home VM I installed. Just for the record, last time I used Hyper-V I There was this "Remote FX" plugin that is no longer supported so. Anyways does anyone have any idea how to solve this? As far as I know I am up to date.

Comment: did you use quick create or install manually?  You need xRDP for enhanced session to work.  Using quick create will pre-config Unbuntu to work with enhanced session. RemoteFX isn't relevant and is now deprecated. See my answer here for manually changing the resolution: https://superuser.com/questions/1475849/how-to-change-vm-resoulition-to-higher-hyper-v/1476427#1476427

Comment: On windows how do I check if I have XRDP installed? This is something I can install on LINUX, I just checked and tried but for Windows? I also can't edit grub, somehow POP_OS is not using it or not at the specific location.

Comment: POP_OS is likely not using it. Start here: https://github.com/microsoft/linux-vm-tools/wiki/Onboarding:-Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been open for a while but I had a slightly similar issue very recently.  Had a Windows 2019 Hyper-V server with multiple VMs (Linux, Windows 10,8, Server 2016, 2019 etc), enhanced sessions were working on all of them.  Then one day the enhanced session option was greyed out and unavailable for all the VMs.  Drove me mad until I noticed a rogue GPO that had "Restrict delegation of credentials to remote servers" policy enabled. Disabled it, gpupdate /force on the Hyper-V server and enhanced session was available again.  Just for reference GPO setting is computer configuration - policies - administrative templates - system - credentials delegation.  Local group policy would be computer configuration - administrative templates - system - credentials delegation of course.